# How to set custom NSSplitView with NSSplitViewController?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nssplitview, nssplitviewcontroller

I'd like to use a custom `NSSplitView` with my `NSSplitViewController`.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssplitviewcontroller/1388907-splitview) say:

> To provide a custom split view, set this property at any time before
>   you call super in the inherited viewDidLoad() method; that is, before
>   the split view controller’s isViewLoaded property is true.

My `NSSplitViewController` subclass is called `MainVC`.

I tried setting my custom split view in `-viewDidLoad` before calling `[super viewDidLoad]`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.splitView = [MySplitView new];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Rest of viewDidLoad...
}
```

but it didn't work. I got the following error:

> 2017-09-02 10:35:43.527312-0700 Zee[6497:632581] ** *** Assertion
>   failure in -[MainVC setSplitView:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-
>   1561/Controllers/NSSplitViewController.m:220**
>
> 2017-09-02 10:35:43.527558-0700 Zee[6497:632581] **MainVC: The
>   -splitView can only be assigned before the view is loaded**

I also tried overriding `loadView`:

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.splitView = [MySplitView new];
    [super loadView];
}
```

But I get:

> 2017-09-02 10:39:39.377345-0700 Zee[6575:639146] ** *** -[__NSArrayM
>   objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array**

If I do the assignment after calling `[super loadView]`, I get the same error as I did when I tried it in `-viewDidLoad`.

How do I use a custom `NSSplitView` in my `NSSplitViewController` subclass?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to make the custom split view with the NSSplitViewController? What are you looking to gain from subclassing both NSSplitView and NSSplitViewController?

Comment: @LucasDerraugh I'd like to customize the appearance of the divider and subclassing NSSplitView seems to be the way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the index out of bounds issue is related to your split view not having any content rather than something you're doing wrong with initialization. Leaving the initialization in the loadView should be fine. Simply make sure you have initialized your NSSplitViewController subclass with at least 2 NSSplitViewItems before presenting it. Here's an example:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    MySplitViewController *vc = [MySplitViewController new];
    vc.splitViewItems = @[
        [NSSplitViewItem splitViewItemWithViewController:[MyViewController new]],
        [NSSplitViewItem splitViewItemWithViewController:[MyViewController new]]
    ];
    self.window.contentViewController = vc;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer in this thread is technically correct, but (understandably) misses a bug in `NSSplitViewController` that I haven't found documented anywhere. Such is the state of Cocoa development in 2017, I guess...

Anyway, the issue is this: if you're like me and wanted to use an `NSSplitViewController` with an `NSSplitView` that *starts* with just one view, the subclassing approach above won't work and you'll get the indexing error from OP. There's a private method (for drawing the divider) that assumes two `NSSplitViewItem`'s are in there at all times, even though `NSSplitView` works fine with just one.

What I ended up doing is subclassing both `NSSplitViewController` and `NSSplitView`, and providing a check for if I create one that only has one view and swapping in a blank `NSViewController` instance that gets removed once the loading phase has settled down. I've also found that setting `splitViewController.splitViewItems = ...` directly doesn't work well, and you should be calling through to `addSplitViewItem:` to do this - presumably there's some stuff behind the scenes that you miss out on otherwise.

This class is annoyingly not documented, even though it's pretty useful overall. If you're a wayward traveler and you find this, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the additional color.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this worked. (macOS 10.14, Xcode 10)

```
final class SplitVC: NSSplitViewController {
    private func patch() {
        let v = NSSplitView()
        v.isVertical = true
        v.dividerStyle = .thin
        splitView = v
        splitViewItems = [
            NSSplitViewItem(viewController: NSTabViewController()),
            NSSplitViewItem(viewController: NSTabViewController()),
        ]
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: NSNib.Name?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        patch()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        patch()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across what I think is the source of this issue. It occurs in the default implementation of `splitView(_ splitView: NSSplitView, shouldHideDividerAt dividerIndex: Int) -> Bool`. I think Apple is incorrectly indexing in that method which leads to the out of bounds errors.

To skip calling their implementation, just override it in your `NSSplitViewController` subclass:

```swift
  override func splitView(_ splitView: NSSplitView, shouldHideDividerAt dividerIndex: Int) -> Bool {
    false
  }
```

If you instead call `super.shouldHideDividerAt(...)` the errors start happening again:

```
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
```

---

The solution others provide of adding "dummy" splitViewItems worked for me, until I added an override for `insertSplitViewItem` and looked at the `.view.frame` or `.splitViewItems` of my NSSplitViewController subclass, then the out-of-bounds errors came back and I was stuck again.

After getting frustrated I went to GitHub to see if I could luck out and find someone working around the bug. I came across this comment/code: https://github.com/MoonfishDeFi/Composite/blob/1ccde807c690739b1739e22f02213e195265a992/cotEditor/Document%20Window/Document%20View/SplitViewController.swift#L62 which has this solution but no explanation.